# To neglect the percentage of people expected to have the disease: Is this a Base Rate Fallacy?

Tags: logic, fallacies

Would this be an example of the base rate fallacy in medicine?

When people commit the “base rate fallacy” in medical diagnoses, they neglect the percentage of people who are expected to have the disease.

I think it is but if I am wrong, please explain to me why. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct, but a little more specifics are valuable, because there's many ways one can "neglect the percentages."  Base rate fallacy can cause people to believe that a medical test is more valuable for determining whether one has a disease than it actually is.

One example of this is heart attack symptoms.  One of the great frustrations for groups trying to help with the detection of heart attacks and saving lives is just how hard it is to identify a definitive symptom.  Most healthy individuals will experience at least one heart attack symptom at least once in their life.  Chest pain presents quite reliably in male heart attacks, but because it occurs in healthy individuals, and there are so many more healthy individuals than individuals suffering a heart attack, chest pains are not actually as good of a sign as one would like.  If you are a hypochondriac suffering from extreme anxiety about heart related issues, you may commit a base rate fallacy by presuming your chest pain is an indication that you are likely having a heart attack, when in fact many chest pains are not heart attacks.

*Disclaimer: Seek medical attention if you think you need it!  I am not a doctor!  That being said, if you are a hypochondriac suffering from anxiety due to this base rate fallacy, know that there are other signs of a heart attack which have a lower false-positive rate (such as those which consider the rate of onset of pain) which your doctor may be able to go over with you to form an educated opinion on the matter.*

The best example of base rate fallacy I have seen is one regarding TSA and terrorism, and its easy enough to turn into a medical version of the same story.  In this version, you develop a test to detect terrorists.  It has a false positive rate of 0.1% (a non-terrorist is flagged as a terrorist), and a false negative rate of 0% (no terrorist ever fails to be flagged).  If a person is flagged by the system, what's the probability they are a terrorist?  If you commit the base rate fallacy, you will believe it is highly likely that a flagged person is a terrorist, because it catches all terrorists and only a fraction of non-terrorists.  This fallacy occurs because you underestimate just how few terrorists there are compared to normal people.

Roughly 3 million people fly per day, so 0.1% is about 3 thousand people.  That means there will be 3 thousand people flagged every single day that are innocent -- false positives.  Now we don't know for sure how many terrorists fly, but given that there are 0 documented cases of a terrorist being stopped by TSA (unknown whether there are any classified instances or not), we can presume its quite low... almost certainly well below 1 terrorist per day.  So, when you do not commit the base rate fallacy, you see that the probability of someone who is flagged actually being a terrorist is quite low, well under 1%, and likely a thousandth of a percent or less (depending on the actual number of terrorists thwarted by TSA, which is not public knowledge).

Comment: Please tell me if this modification offends; did you have a special reason for writing 0.0% instead of 0%?

Comment: @LePressentiment That's fine by me.  I believe I was matching the number of digits between 0.1% and 0.0% because I find a lot of situations where matching the units and number of decimal points helps to make the comparisons clearer.  In this case, I don't think it matters either way, I'm just in the habit of writing the extra digit.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I modified it to 0% because I ceased reading for 2 mins to wonder whether 0.0% was missing decimals right of the tenth digit (or I am idiotic).